# Click the item of listview then display a viewpager

Tags: listview, android-viewpager, expandablelistview

I am creating an application. I have a photo `ListView`, each item of the `ListView` is a folder containing image. When I click an item of the ListView I want it to displayed a ViewPager (like gallery). How can I achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: Thank you, I have completed